# Virtues applied for a community (Correct word choice?)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

I wrote 2 sentences:

Many ethnic groups migrated into what is now Vietnamese territory at different times in history: some came thousands of years ago and some came hundreds of years ago. Regardless of that, any people who have settled on the S-shaped country* are considered to be of the same roots and also brothers and sisters united by **understanding, faithfulness, attachment and mutual care**.

*Vietnam is a long, narrow nation shaped like the letter S.

I don't know if my word choice for all the virtues here applies for a group of people. What I think they meant when applying for a community are

- understanding: people of a community understand and feel sympathy for
  each other
- faithfulness: people of a community remains unchanging in feelings towards each other
- attachment: people of a community having tight-knit relationship with
  each other
- mutual care: people of a community will love, help and protect each
  other

Comment: It sounds OK to me, but we are getting into the territory of 'writing advice' rather than English language.

Comment: I'd change "faithfulness" to "loyalty". "Faithfulness" sound like it has to do with a common religion